Typescript can't use value to index object type that satisfies another type with that value
Sorry for the convoluted title.
I have this in typescript:
type EthereumAddress = `0x${string}`

type Chain = 'eth'

type ApiMethods = {
  getToken(args: {
    tokenAddress: EthereumAddress
  }): string

  getRank(args: {
    tokenAddress: EthereumAddress
  }): string
}

type ApiPaths<M extends ApiMethods> = {
  [K in keyof M]: {
    path: string
    chain?: Chain
  }
}

const apiPaths = {
  getToken: {
    path: 'tokens/',
    chain: 'eth'
  },

  getRank: {
    path: 'rank/',
  }
} as const satisfies ApiPaths<ApiMethods>

I would like to construct a Paths type which is a union of all possible paths the api can take. If the apiPaths has a chain parameter, the path should be ${path}/${chain}, if not ${path}.
I tried doing this:
type Paths<T extends typeof apiPaths = typeof apiPaths> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends {chain: Chain}
    ? `${T[K]['path']}${T[K]['chain']}/`
    : `${T[K]['path']}`
}[keyof T]

But I get the error:
Type 'T[K]["path"]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.ts(2322)
Type '"path"' cannot be used to index type 'T[K]'.

Why is path not a recognised parameter of T[K] if it is clearly mentioned in all apiPaths values and especially if apiPaths satisfies ApiPaths<ApiMethods>?

Paths<typeof apiPaths & { whoopsie: string }>; That's why. extends means you can have more properties, among other things. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz yes this does address the question thanks.

@jcalz Well but if it can have MORE properties, why would it affect properties that it has for sure ?

? It doesn't affect properties it has for sure, but K isn't known to be one of those. K could be anything at all (like "whoopsie" in the example I gave), and T[K] might not have a path property, so T[K]["path"] is an error.  You'll need to check that T[K] has  a path property before you can index it, or convince the compiler of it. Does that make sense now or is there still some confusion?

(See prev comment) essentially there's no reason for you to have made Paths generic if you only wanted K extends keyof typeof apiPaths. Instead you put a T in there which could have any number of extra properties. If you just use tyepof apiPaths in place of T it works just fine. But note, you didn't ask "how should I have done this" but "why is there an error here"? Let me know how you'd like to proceed here.

@jcalz. Thanks, everything is clear. If you want to answer the question also adding how I should’ve done it I’d appreciate it a lot. Thanks.

The problem with your Paths<T> type is that T is a generic type constrained to typeof apiPaths. That means it might be some extension of typeof apiPaths with extra properties not present in typeof apiPaths, and nothing requires those properties to have a path property.  For example:
type ApiPathsWithRaisins = typeof apiPaths & {raisins: true};
type Oops = Paths<ApiPathsWithRaisins>; 

Since Paths<T> is defined as
type Paths<T extends typeof apiPaths = typeof apiPaths> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { chain: Chain }
  ? `${T[K]['path']}${T[K]['chain']}/`
  : `${T[K]['path']}`
}[keyof T]

then for Paths<ApiPathsWithRaisins>, K will iterate over "getToken" | "getRank" | "raisins".  And when K is raisins, T[K] is true, and true does not have a known member named path. So you cannot safely assume that T[K] will have a path property.
That's the source of the error. Again, typeof apiPaths is known to have a path property at every key, but T does not.

You could fix it in any number of ways.  If all you care about is computing Paths<typeof apiPaths> then you don't actually need generics at all. Just substitute typeof apiPaths instead of T and it will work:
type MyApiPaths = typeof apiPaths;
type Paths = {
  [K in keyof MyApiPaths]: MyApiPaths[K] extends { chain: Chain }
  ? `${MyApiPaths[K]['path']}${MyApiPaths[K]['chain']}/`
  : `${MyApiPaths[K]['path']}`
}[keyof MyApiPaths]
// type Paths = "rank/" | "tokens/eth/"

Or perhaps even something like
type Paths = keyof { [T in MyApiPaths[keyof MyApiPaths]
  as T extends { chain: infer C extends Chain } ? `${T["path"]}${C}/` : T['path']]: 0
}
// type Paths = "rank/" | "tokens/eth/"

Or, if you do want to use generics, you just need to be sure that it is properly constrained to something where every property has a string-like path property:
type GoodPaths<T extends Record<keyof T, { path: string }> = typeof apiPaths> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { chain: Chain }
  ? `${T[K]['path']}${T[K]['chain']}/`
  : `${T[K]['path']}`
}[keyof T]
type OK = GoodPaths;
// type OK = "rank/" | "tokens/eth/"

Playground link to code
